# Why does slaying the hydra require infinite ordinals?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ordinals

I have recently come across the problem of the mathematical 
hydra. More information can be found [here](https://markhkim.com/foundtechnicalities/killing-the-hydra/) or a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWwUpEY4c8o).

I have to say that I don't fully understand why infinite ordinals are required to prove the hydra can always be killed. For example, here is how I would go about it.

Represent the hydra as a decorated tree so that leaf nodes are grouped
together and represented by a single number on an edge leading to a 
representative node as shown below. [a bit awkward to represent in ASCII, 
but here goes]

```
(r denotes the root, 1-multiplicity labels are omitted so o-[1]-o = o-o)

r
o-o-o
   \
    o

= 

r
o-o-[2]-o

since there are 2 leaf nodes in that branch.
```

Then by repeatedly applying the cut move:

$o-[A]-o-[B]-o \ \ \ \  \ \rightarrow \ \ \ \ \ o-[A(m+1)^B]-o + A((m+1)^B - 1)/m$

where the first term on the RHS changes the tree, the second term counts the number of cuts needed to perform the cut move, and m is the number of new copies spawned,

the height of each branch is decreasing and the height of the tree is always non-increasing as the number of cuts is being tallied. Eventually this leaves us with just the root and the total number of cuts required to kill the hydra.

Since the hydra is finite and the number of cuts added with each cut move, $A((m+1)^B - 1)/m$, is finite, then the total number of cuts is therefore always finite and so the hydra will always be killed.

So where does this strategy either go wrong or invoke infinite ordinals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea works only for a certain very special class of strategies: strategies that preserve the symmetry of the hydra inherent in your labelling scheme.  That is, by labelling "repeated" edges with numbers, each "head" in your graph actually represents many different heads of the hydra, one for each possible choice of a single edge from every repeated edge below it.  You then assume that every time you cut off one head of the hydra, you also immediately cut off all other heads which are represented by the same point in your graph.  In this way, by just changing the numerical labels, you guarantee that the graph only shrinks as you cut.

However, an arbitrary strategy does not need to do this.  It can cut off one head but not also cut off all the other "copies" of it, destroying the symmetry of the graph.  In order to correctly represent the hydra, you would then need to add new branches to your graph, and so your argument falls apart.

---

[Old response, based on a misunderstanding of your strategy, preserved since it still may be helpful to some readers:]

I am somewhat confused by your notation and don't know how you got the specific numbers you wrote, but I believe you have in mind a correct simple strategy for defeating any hydra.  To be a bit more precise, here's the strategy.  Pick a head of maximal height, and repeatedly cut off all maximal height heads from that head's grandfather until you have eliminated all such heads (it is not difficult to show this will happen eventually).  Doing this to all the grandfather nodes of heads of maximal height, you will reduce the height of the tree.  Now repeat until the height of the tree is reduced to $0$.

This strategy requires nothing involving ordinals, and indeed can be proven to be a successful strategy in PA.  What requires something like ordinals (or at least, some technique which cannot be performed in PA) is proving that *every* strategy is successful.  That is, no matter what strategy you use for cutting off heads, you will eventually defeat the hydra.  This is a much stronger statement than just finding a single strategy that works!

Comment: The interested Reader might like [Is it really impossible to lose the Hydra game?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794864/is-it-really-impossible-to-lose-the-hydra-game)

Comment: Thanks, I am already aware of this difference. But my construction above allows any head to be removed rather than just the maximal height ones, which is why I'm asking since it doesn't follow a specific strategy as such and so could (?) encompass every strategy.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow your argument at all then.  I don't understand what your "cut move" is, if it's supposed to be representing a completely arbitrary cut.  Note that when you cut off a head, the tree above the grandfather node may be much more complicated than just o-[A]-o-[B]-o.

Comment: I will draw some pictures and get back to you - hopefully it will make it easier to understand what I mean.

Comment: OK, here are some examples: http://imgur.com/a/GYmLo

Comment: What you are saying still does not apply to _arbitrary_ strategies.  You are assuming that every time you cut off one head, you also cut off all the other "copies" of that head in other "copies" of its branch given by edges you've labelled with numbers.  An arbitrary strategy doesn't have to do that at all.

Comment: For instance, in the final tree of your third example, what happens if next you cut off one of the heads at the top of the tree?  Because of the edge labelled 9 far below it, there are actually 9 "copies" of that head, and if you cut off just one of them, the symmetry of your tree is destroyed and you have to actually draw two separate branches instead of just drawing it once and labelling an edge with 9.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I guess the way I have set it up it is impossible to cut off only 1 of the 9 heads, so as you say it's not really an arbitrary strategy. Thank you again.